# (Python) Why is my while loop not working?

Tags: python, while-loop, python-3.8

I have been working on an operating system inside of Python and I am starting off with the system booting code. I have a while loop that executes when the variable "Booting" = 1. Inside the while loop is a script that prints "Booting" then replaces that with "Booting.", then it gets replaced with "Booting.." and so on until it reaches "Booting....." which should make it reset to "Booting" and reset the cycle. Instead, it just stops at "Booting....." and doesn't continue to reset the cycle.

Here is the code:

```
import time
import sys

Booting = 1

while Booting == 1:
 print("Booting")
 sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
 time.sleep(0.2)
 print("Booting.")
 sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
 time.sleep(0.2)
 print("Booting..")
 sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
 time.sleep(0.2)
 print("Booting...")
 sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
 time.sleep(0.2)
 print("Booting....")
 sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
 time.sleep(0.2)
 print("Booting.....")
 sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
 time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Can't repro. The loop runs forever on my machine.

Comment: well, looks like it's working just fine - you have infinite loop

Comment: his question isnt about the loop being infinite ... its about he is not seeing his first print after the loop iterates (the escape moves the cursor, but doesnt overwrite the line)

Comment: @JoranBeasley, the only real question in this question (pun intended) is the title _Why is my while loop not working?_

Comment: valid point ;P but to him he was expecting it to reset to zero periods ... but it appeared not to so i can sort of see why he thought it was just hanging at the end ... that said some basic debugging should have shown it was indeed looping  (ie if he removed the ESC reset position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does not erase the rest of the line, so you need to replace any existing variables you want to overwrite with spaces

try

```
...
print("booting    ")
...
print("booting.   ")
...
```

etc

(there are many ways to clear the line this is just one (@code provides another good alternative in the comments)

Comment: Or instead at the end of each loop just run `print(" " * 12)`.

Comment: Thanks, that works! I just have to wait 9 minutes to accept your answer.

Comment: @code yes that is a very valid solution